# Dropbox API iOS isn't uploading files

Tags: ios, dropbox-api

I am added dropbox support to my app, everything works perfect, the authentication, the login/out, but I can't upload files. I am using

```
NSArray *p = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* docDir = [p objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *localPath = docDir;
    NSString *filename = @"Documents";
    NSString *destDir = @"/";
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath];
```

to upload my applications /Document directory to Dropbox, but nothing is uploaded. I don't get any error message. The directory Apps/My-Applications-Name is created, but with no content inside.

Anyone know why?

I also have this two delegate methods, but I still don't get a log. I also have `<DBRestClientDelegate>` behind the `@interface … ()`:

```
- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadedFile:(NSString*)destPath
              from:(NSString*)srcPath metadata:(DBMetadata*)metadata {

    NSLog(@"File uploaded successfully to path: %@", metadata.path);
}

- (void)restClient:(DBRestClient*)client uploadFileFailedWithError:(NSError*)error {
    NSLog(@"File upload failed with error - %@", error);

}
```

Comment: You can't upload a folder, only specific files. And the file that you specify needs to be full file path, not just the filename.

Comment: So the filename must be the file Path?

Comment: Sorry, I meant the `fromPath` argument needs to be the full pathname. I guess you can ignore the 2nd half of my first comment.

Comment: What response do you get?

Comment: I don't get any response, but the method is called.

Comment: @DavidG. - where you able to solve your issue?

Comment: Slightly a bit behind the date of this question, but when you say the method is called, how do you know?  I believe Dropbox creates the application directory when you make the first connection to it, not each time you try to upload a file, so the directory's existence is not a clue.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like `Documents` is a directory, but `uploadFile` is used to upload a file. I don't think there's a method in the Core API to upload the contents of a folder, so you'll have to walk through the folder and upload each file individually.

Comment: OK, now I tried to upload a file from my bundle: NSString *localPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"png" ofType:@"png"]; it didn't worked either.

Comment: Oh don't know much about iOS development, but I would take a look at `localPath` and make sure it's what you expect. Wouldn't this only work for a file called "png.png" (which seems like an unlikely filename).

Comment: png.png is the icon for the file type .png, thats why it is called png.png. I used the methode from the Dropbox tutorial, but it doesn't work either.

Comment: When you say that "it doesn't work," what exactly do you mean? Do you get an error? What happens?

Comment: I get nothing, no Log, nothing. I am using the code from Dropbox itself.

Comment: And the reason you're saying "it doesn't work" is because the `uploadedFile` delegate isn't called? Or is it called? Does the file show up in Dropbox?

Comment: The methode is called, I set a breakpoint, so the app is stopping when the method is called.

Comment: Would you please tell me why you say "it doesn't work"? How is what you're seeing different from what you would expect to see if it were working?

Comment: I expect some Error message in the log, but I get nothing, no Error message and no file in Dropbox, nor is one of the delegate methods called.

Comment: I thought you just said earlier today that the `uploadedFile` delegate *was* being called. Assuming the delegates aren't, in fact, being called, I would double check that you're actually registering for them. Do you have a line of code like `restClient.delegate = self`?

Comment: I added restClient.delegate = self, but still no log or anything even thought the line [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil fromPath:localPath]; is called.

Comment: Maybe you can share your current full code (without app key and secret, of course)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement the Dropbox delegate methods? Uploadcompleted and uploadfailedwitherror? You also need to specify in your app delegate that you are the Dropbox delegate in order to implement those methods. Make sure your local path is correct, your upload path is.

Add DBRestClientDelegate to your app delegate or whatever class uploads

Comment: The methods are in my file, but I don't get any responde.

Comment: Have you put DBRestClientDelegate in your header?

Comment: I'm sorry lol I didn't read everything. I read that you do have DBRestClientDelegate

Comment: Nslog your rest client object make sure it's not nil

Comment: NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *localfilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"my-local-path(make this up...)"];

Answer (score 0):

```
NSArray *p = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString* documentDirectory = [p objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *filename = @"png.png";
    NSString *destDir = @"/";
    [[self restClient] uploadFile:filename
                           toPath:destDir
                    withParentRev:nil
             fromPath:[documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename] ];
```

the "fromPath" must be the FULL PATH of the source file. The API Document is WRONG.

Answer (score -1):

Did you check that you're making setting the delegate from the main thread? Otherwise, your thread likely doesn't have a runloop and the delegate callbacks will never be called.

**UPDATE** my problem was ARC destroying the DBRestClient object before the upload was complete.